# Yielding in a web worker - is setTimeout enough, or must I exit too?

Tags: javascript, typescript, settimeout, web-worker

In my web worker I have to do a ton of processing in a loop. In the C# or Java world I would code it up as follows (Java):

```
// main code:
public static void mainLoop() {
    for (Iterator it=getIterator(); it.hasNext() && keepRunning; ) {
        Object item = it.next();
        processThisOne (item);
    }
}

// async method
static boolean keepRunning = true;
public static void abort() {
    keepRunning = false;
}
```

The above won't work in a web worker. While the main loop is running above now subsequent postMessage() calls will be processed.

I can do the following (now in typescript):

```
// kicked off by postMessage event handler
public mainLoop () : void {
    if (! keepRunning)
        return;
    Object item = it.next();
    processThisOne (item);
    worker.setTimeout(mainLoop, 0);
}

// also callable by postMessage event handler:
static boolean keepRunning = true;
public static void abort() {
    keepRunning = false;
}
```

Instead, can I basically yield as follows? And if so, is this as fast (there are task switches going on between the threads on a setTimeout)?

```
// kicked off by postMessage event handler
public mainLoop () : void {
    for (Iterator it=getIterator(); it.hasNext() && keepRunning; ) {
        Object item = it.next();
        processThisOne (item);

        // yield
        worker.setTimeout(nothing, 0);
    }
}

// called by setTimeout:
public static void nothing() {
}

// also callable by postMessage event handler:
static boolean keepRunning = true;
public static void abort() {
    keepRunning = false;
}
```

If the above works then my code stays simpler. The question is, does a setTimeout() yield? Or does it just queue up that call for after the processing I am presently performing ends?

Comment: Where does `it` get the items from?

Comment: So you want to call `abort()` from another postMessage handler, to intercept the "loop"?

Comment: @Bergi - No, I just want to call yield so in the middle of processing one postMessage I can get another.

Answer (score 0):

I've run some tests and I believe that answer is you must exit the method you're in. setTimeout() queue's up the method, but won't run it till there's nothing running in the web worker.